# How does God help people?

Tags: belief

A person suffered huge losses in his education and career for 20 years because of depression & anxiety. Who should be blamed for that: he himself or God?

After 20 years of suffering, he overcame it and reestablished his education, career, and income. Who should be given credit for his recovery: he himself or God?

Comment: No event occurs spontaneously, out of nothing , uncaused (as per tenets).The onus of happenings is according to the doctrine of karma. A Credit or blame does not bind God.

Comment: The answer is yes to all. By actions & consequences. Have to close as opinion-based, though.